# How to update an item in array while setting state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need help in optimizing this code

```
eatMushroom = (foundMushroom, startTime, steps) => {
  const updatedMushrooms = this.state.mushrooms;
  updatedMushrooms[foundMushroom.key].remaining = false;
  this.setState({
    mushrooms: updatedMushrooms,
    score: this.state.score + 1
  });

  if (this.totalMushrooms === this.state.score) {
    this.props.setTotalTime(startTime, steps);
    this.props.history.push("/score");
  }
};
```

I this it's taking a toll on performance when replace complete array in state, while I just want to update a single item.

Comment: you are updating ony score?

Comment: use spread operator

Comment: Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs

Comment: Avoid mutating original state array. Use spread operator like this `const updatedMushrooms = [...this.state.mushrooms];`

Comment: Even in this case we are updating the complete array in the state isn't it?

Comment: Even after `const updatedMushrooms = [...this.state.mushrooms]`, performance is still the same

Comment: @Shreyas My comment was not to improve performance. It is just a recommended practice to not mutate state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a better practice first of all you should avoid mutating state and if you are gonna need values from state while updating state you should consider using functional state updates. This will help on getting the correct values always.

Another thing to consider is that you are using `this.state.score` right after setting it. `setState` is async and can occur after you do your `if` statement. For this you should consider using callbacks.

Below is the modified version of your code with the suggestions above;

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  const mushrooms = Object.assign({}, prevState.mushrooms);
  mushrooms[foundMushroom.key].remaining = false;
  return { mushrooms, score: (prevState.score + 1) };
}, () => {
  if (this.totalMushrooms === this.state.score) {
    this.props.setTotalTime(startTime, steps);
    this.props.history.push("/score");
  }
});
```

I don't know how are you using `this.state.mushrooms` value but for better performance you can do a little change. If you want to modify only one property then you should move your properties one level up. `mushrooms` property is unnecessary in my opinion.

**Example Data**

Rather then using like below

```
this.state = {
  mushrooms: {
    mushA: {
      remaining: true
    },
    mushB: {
      remaining: false
    },
    mushC: {
      remaining: true
    }
  }
};
```

You can use like this

```
this.state = {
  mushA: {
    remaining: true
  },
  mushB: {
    remaining: false
  },
  mushC: {
    remaining: true
  }
};
```

This way you can update your state like below. One property at a time and I believe this would result in a better performance updates.

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  const mushroom = Object.assign({}, prevState[foundMushroom.key], { remaining: false });
  return { [foundMushroom.key]: mushroom, score: (prevState.score + 1) };
}, () => {
  if (this.totalMushrooms === this.state.score) {
    this.props.setTotalTime(startTime, steps);
    this.props.history.push("/score");
  }
});
```